# Cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with countable points missing

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

It is a simple application of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence and induction to show that if $X_k$ is the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $k$ points missing, then it's de Rham cohomology is given by:

$$H^0_{DR}(X_k) = \mathbb{R}$$
$$H^{n-1}_{DR}(X_k) = \mathbb{R}^k$$

What happens if an infinite amount of points is missing? If I remove a countable quantity of points on $\mathbb{R}^n$, does it yield a infinite dimensional $H_{n-1}$? Does it depend on topological properties of this set? (if the removed points are dense, for example).

Comment: Yes, it does depend on the topological properties of this set. E.g. if you remove a countably infinite discrete set, your space is homotopy equivalent to an infinite wedge of spheres and $H^1=\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty \Bbb R$. On the other hand, if you remove everything except for a point, you end up with trivial $H^1$.